# Using Authorization filter in JSF project for custom authentication

Tags: jsf, servlet-filters

i have embedded log in / log out functionality in my application but the filter is probably not working as i can still see the pages after logging out when i point them in the browser address bar. Here is my login action:-

```
this.currentUser = new User();  // initiate currentUser
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
facesContext.getApplication().createValueBinding("#{" + Constants.VISIT_KEY_SCOPE +
Constants.VISIT_KEY + "}").setValue(facesContext, currentUser);
FacesUtils.putIntoSession(Constants.VISIT_KEY, currentUser);
```

Logout action:-

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
HttpSession session = (HttpSession)facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
session.removeAttribute(Constants.VISIT_KEY_SCOPE + Constants.VISIT_KEY);

 if (session != null)
    {
     session.invalidate();
    }
```

Constants Class:-

```
public class Constants
{
  // Backing bean keys
 public final static String VISIT_KEY_SCOPE = "sessionScope.";
 public final static String VISIT_KEY = "currentUser";

 // Model object keys
 public final static String PROJECT_COORDINATOR_SCOPE = "applicationScope.";


  public final static String ORIGINAL_VIEW_SCOPE = "sessionScope";
  public final static String ORIGINAL_VIEW_KEY = "originalTreeId";
  }
```

The web.xml:-

```
 <filter>
 <filter-name>AuthorizationFilter</filter-name>
 <filter-class>org.AuthorizationFilter.AuthorizationFilter</filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
 <filter-name>AuthorizationFilter</filter-name>
 <url-pattern>/faces/pages/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
```

and finally the authorization filter is as follows:-

```
public class AuthorizationFilter implements Filter
{
 FilterConfig config = null;
 ServletContext servletContext = null;

 public AuthorizationFilter()
 {
 }

 public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException
 {
  config = filterConfig;
  servletContext = config.getServletContext();
  }

  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                   FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException
     {
       HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest)request;
       HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse)response;
       HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession();

       User currentUser = (User)session.getAttribute("currentUser");

    if (session  == null || currentUser == null || currentUser.getUserName() == null)
     {
      session.setAttribute(Constants.ORIGINAL_VIEW_KEY, httpRequest.getPathInfo());
      httpResponse.sendRedirect(httpRequest.getContextPath() +  "/faces/pages  
       /login.jsp");
      }
     else
        {
         session.removeAttribute(Constants.ORIGINAL_VIEW_KEY);
         chain.doFilter(request, response);
         } 

         }

          public void destroy()
          {
           }
           }
```

Bundles of thanks for patience and help.

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell the browser to *not* cache the restricted pages for which you need to check if the user is logged in. Otherwise the browser will just display the page from the cache and hereby never invoke your filter. You could do that by adding the following lines to the `else` block in your filter *before* calling `FilterChain#doFilter()`:

```
httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
httpResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
httpResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, there are some flaws in your code:

1. `session.removeAttribute()` in your logout action will possibly throw `NullPointerException` because you passed `false` in `getSession()`. That line is superflous when you're going to call `session.invalidate()` anyway. Just remove it.
2. `request.getSession()` in your filter never returns `null` because you aren't passing `false` to it. So the `session == null` is superfluous or you must add `false`.

Comment: hi BalusC. Thanks for reply. i have added the lines for "cache removal". and addressed points 1 and 2 that u mentioned. Application is not throwing any error but the pages still show up when the address to them is written in the browser. any idea where to look for it?